# In dropdown list, onchange function is works only when change in the first item ?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my html code the list item is from the database using foreach loop:

```
 <select class="form-control select" id="inventoryitem" name="inventoryitem" onchange="getunit();">
     <option>---select item---</option>
     <?php foreach($item as $i) { ?> 
     <option><?php echo $i->Name; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

This is my script code:

```
function getunit()
{
  var item = $('#inventoryitem').val();
  alert(item);
}
```

Comment: What do you actually wanted to achieve ??

Comment: Please give more specific details to understand your actual problem.

Comment: Only when change in first item means what you are trying to get

Comment: You can use jquery onready function. if you want your function to work on page load...
`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  yourFunction();
}); 
</script>
`
Hope this is what you want

Comment: i got list items in the list box but my problem is that 'onchange' function is does not works all the item selected, the function work only when first item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove onchange="getunit();" from your select 
and try the code below:

```
$( "#inventoryitem" ).change(function() {
  var item = $( "#inventoryitem option:selected" ).text();
  alert(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will stop function if any of them has errors,
please make sure all your javascript is well functioning.

```
$(function(){
  $("#inventoryitem").change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val); // Instead of alert i prefer you to use console
  })
})
```